# to save gnome-terminal in a file

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I am using the following command to open a terminal and execute an script. How to save the output to a log file.

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "print1.py; read -n1" &
```

I tried following options but didn't succeed. Kindly suggest a solution.

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "print1.py; read -n1" & > log.txt
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "print1.py; read -n1" & | tee log.txt
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "print1.py; read -n1" & | tee -a log.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `read` is just for interactivity, try saving the output inside the `bash` command:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "print1.py | tee log.txt; read -n1" &
```

Comment: @Vinesh *if* the answer solved your problem, as you indicated, would you be so kind to accept the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `script` to save all the output to a file.

```
[morris@rhel tmp]$ script output.log
Script started, file is output.log
[morris@rhel tmp]$ uname -r
3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64
[morris@rhel tmp]$ exit
Script done, file is output.log
[morris@rhel tmp]$ cat output.log 
Script started on Sun 18 Jun 2017 06:55:39 PM HKT
[morris@rhel tmp]$ uname -r
3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64
[morris@rhel tmp]$ exit

Script done on Sun 18 Jun 2017 06:55:48 PM HKT
[morris@rhel tmp]$
```

with `gnome-terminal`, something like bellow may work.

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "script -c 'print1.py; read -n1' output.log; who -a;" &
```

Comment: Is there a way to save the output after the fact...ie when you've been running stuff and then suddenly decide you want to save it all?

Comment: I am not sure, I think no way to save the output if it has been truncated by the terminal. Maybe you can try `select all` and copy & paste manually.